rust, building from source, cross build of native compiler
I am searching a way to build a native version of rustc in cross mode from source code. I have a specific target-A and libLLVM with backend for this target-A. So there are a two copies of libLLVM. One for cross compilation to target-A, and other for native compilation.
The standard rust infrastructure doesn't support target-A.
I succeeded to build a cross version of rustc for target-A. I use a next config.toml (shorten version):
[build]
build = "x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu"  
host = "x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu"
target = ["x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu", "A-unknown-linux-gnu"]
cargo = "/path/to/cargo"
rustc = "/path/to/rustc"

extended = true

[llvm]
link-shared = true

[target.x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu]
llvm-config = "/path/to/crossA/llvm-config"
cc = "gcc"
cxx = "g++"   

[target.A-unknown-linux-gnu]
llvm-config = "/path/to/crossA/llvm-config"
cc = "gcc-cross-A"
cxx = "g++-cross-A"

And in this case I use the libLLVM with cross version of target-A backend. As the result I get a rustc-crossA, which works on x86, but can build code for target-A.
Is it possible to tune the config.toml file to build on x86 a native rustc for target-A using rustc-crossA? Or are there other solutions?

Well if you already have a "rustc which works on x86 and builds code for target-A" don't you just need to use it as your build.rustc. (Possibly also changing build.cargo to a cross compiler)

How to set llvm-config? Native libLLVM has native llvm-config and the last can't be used. Cross llvm-config from cross libLLVM doesn't fit, I think.

Why wouldn't it fit, if it's meant to build executables for target-A, it'll build a compiler for target-A, after all, a compiler is just an executable.

As I see x.py calls llvm-config during rust building process. If build=x86 so native llvm-config can't be execute. But possibly llvm has feature to build a cross version of llvm-config inside native library?

Currently build process is working. So let's see. (llvm-config is cross, host and target are target-A, rustc and cargo are cross.)

some example: DESTDIR=/path/to/install/in 
./x install -i --stage 1 --host aarch64-apple-darwin.json --target aarch64-apple-darwin 
compiler/rustc library/std

maybe you may build rustc itself this way, and run it on target-a for using it natively on target-a?

@alex, you are right, in this way I really got a native version of rustc + cargo + rustlib (without rustfmt and etc)
